# SharePoint - Change List View Threshold Dynamically CodeBehind

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, query, list-view-threshold

My current SP List View exceeds the threshold limit set in SP Central Admin:

[image]

---

Changing the limit from SPCA is not an option for me as it impacts the performance of other sites.

**Question:** How can I set **List View Lookup Threshold** **dynamically** from code behind?

---

Below is my code:

```
private static DataTable GenerateReport()
{
    DataTable dtAll = new DataTable();

    string subQuery = "<Neq><FieldRef Name =\"ContentType\"/><Value Type=\"Text\">{0}</Value></Neq>".FormatWith("Document");

    try
    {
        SPList recordDocument = SPHelper.GetListByUrl(ErmsConfig.GetString(ErmsConfig.Config.RecordDocument));

        SPView view = recordDocument.GetView(ErmsConfig.GetGuid(ErmsConfig.Config.RecordDocumentFilePlanReportListView));

        SPQuery query1 = new SPQuery(view)
        {
            RowLimit = 0,
        };

        Stopwatch tempWatch = new Stopwatch();

        tempWatch.Start();

        SPListItemCollection primaryHeaders = recordDocument.GetItems(query1);

        int itemCount = primaryHeaders.Count;

        tempWatch.Stop();

        tempWatch.Start();

        var distinctPrimaryHeaders = (from SPListItem item in primaryHeaders select item["Header1Ref"]).Distinct().ToList();

        tempWatch.Stop();

        Stopwatch primaryHeaderWatch = new Stopwatch();

        primaryHeaderWatch.Start();

        foreach (var primaryHeaderRef in distinctPrimaryHeaders)
        {
            try
            {
                Stopwatch folderWatch = new Stopwatch();
                folderWatch.Start();
                SPQuery query = new SPQuery(view)
                {
                    RowLimit = 0,

                    Query = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name =\"Header1Ref\"/><Value Type=\"Text\">{0}</Value></Eq>{1}</And></Where>".FormatWith(primaryHeaderRef, subQuery),
                    ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"",
                    ViewFields = @"
                        <FieldRef Name='Header1Title'/>
                        <FieldRef Name='Header2Title'/>
                        <FieldRef Name='Header3Title'/>
                        <FieldRef Name='FolderTitle'/>
                        <FieldRef Name='FolderRef'/>
                        <FieldRef Name='BusinessOwner'/>
                        <FieldRef Name='RecordTitle'/>
                        <FieldRef Name='RecordLink'/>",
                };

                SPListItemCollection filePlanListing = recordDocument.GetItems(query);

                DataView dv = new DataView(filePlanListing.GetDataTable());

                dv.Sort = "Header1Title, Header2Title, Header3Title";

                dtAll.Merge(dv.ToTable());

                folderWatch.Stop();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Log(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        primaryHeaderWatch.Stop();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return dtAll;
}
```

---

Below is a threshold management code sample.
I tried to modify and integrate into my code but failed..

```
string strQueryMass = @"<Or>
                            <And>
                                <And>
                                    <And>IDPLACEHOLDER</And>
                                    <Eq><FieldRef Name='ContentType' /><Value Type='Text'>ERMS Header Content Type</Value></Eq>
                                </And>
                                <Eq><FieldRef Name='HeaderRef' /><Value Type='Text'>" + strReference + @"</Value></Eq>
                            </And>
                            <And>
                                <And>
                                    <And>IDPLACEHOLDER</And>
                                    <Eq><FieldRef Name='ContentType' /><Value Type='Text'>ERMS Folder Content Type</Value></Eq>
                                </And>
                                <Eq><FieldRef Name='FolderRef' /><Value Type='Text'>" + strReference + @"</Value></Eq>
                            </And>
                        </Or>";
DataTable spliTemp = NoThresholdQuery(MassCreateFolderList, "", "", "<Where>"+strQueryMass+"</Where>");




public DataTable NoThresholdQuery(SPList CIList, string strViewFields, string strViewAttributes, string strQuery)
{

    SPQuery lastIDQuery = new SPQuery();
    lastIDQuery.RowLimit = 1;
    lastIDQuery.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='ID' />";
    lastIDQuery.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy>";
    lastIDQuery.ViewAttributes = "Scope='RecursiveAll'";

    SPListItemCollection LastIDItems = CIList.GetItems(lastIDQuery);

    uint ROWLIMIT = 1000;
    int intTotalLoops = 0;
    if (LastIDItems[0] != null)
    {
        double dblLastID = Convert.ToDouble(LastIDItems[0]["ID"].ToString());
        intTotalLoops = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(dblLastID / ROWLIMIT));
    }
    DataTable resultCollection = new DataTable();

    if (intTotalLoops != 0)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int intLoopCounter = 0; intLoopCounter < intTotalLoops; intLoopCounter++)
            {

                SPQuery listQuery = new SPQuery();
                string strListQuery = strQuery;
                strListQuery = strListQuery.Replace("IDPLACEHOLDER", "<Geq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Integer'>" + ROWLIMIT * (intLoopCounter) + "</Value></Geq><Lt><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Integer'>" + ROWLIMIT * (intLoopCounter + 1) + "</Value></Lt>");

                listQuery.RowLimit = ROWLIMIT;
                if (strViewAttributes != "")
                {
                    listQuery.ViewAttributes = strViewAttributes;
                }
                if (strViewFields != "")
                {
                    listQuery.ViewFields = strViewFields;
                    listQuery.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
                }
                listQuery.Query = strListQuery;
                SPListItemCollection items = CIList.GetItems(listQuery);

                if (items.Count > 0)
                {
                    DataTable dTable1 = items.GetDataTable();
                    if (dTable1 != null)
                    {
                        resultCollection.Merge(dTable1);
                    }
                }
            }
            return resultCollection;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.AddData("Error", "Exception", "Exception", ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return resultCollection;
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable list view threshold for a list using PowerShell code:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ea 0 

$webUrl = "addYourUrlHere"
$list = "addYourListOrLibraryNameHere"

$web = get-spweb $webUrl
$library = $web.Lists[$list]
$library.EnableThrottling = $false
$library.Update()
```

Reference: [Disable the list view threshold for a list or library](http://www.nubo.eu/en/blog/2016/12/Disable-List-View-Threshold-For-A-List-Or-Library/)

Comment: It is worth pointing out that although Kally_MSFT will resolve your issue, you will still experience performance issues. That is because SQL stored procedure will change locking process for the query. If you want to change the list view threshold it will be good idea to lift the site collection to separate content DB. This way you can shield other content from performance degradation caused by queries to the large list.

Comment: Thank you @Kally_MSFT! I will attempt your solution!

Comment: Noted on your point too @MarekSarad!